# installing additional apache modules

Tags: apache, module

I need to enable additional modules for apache eg, mod_proxy, mod_proxy-html, and mod_proxy_balancer.

Is there a way for me to do that without recompiling the whole apache?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system (e. g. which Linux distribution) are you running Apache httpd under?

The common Linux distributions usually come with a mechanism to easily install/enable additional Apache modules, for example a2enmod/a2dismod in Debian and Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You can list the compiled in modules by executing:

```
$ apache2 -l
```

Note: this is NOT `/etc/init.d/apache2`. If the module you need is not already compiled in, you will need to include it inside the configuration file.

See [here](http://www.debuntu.org/2006/06/15/66-how-to-enable-apache-modules-under-debian-based-system) for a Debian/Ubuntu description.

Comment: The description here is terse, but the link to the Debian instructions was very helpful.

Comment: The link is broken, but you can still find it on Archive.org at https://web.archive.org/web/20121117162733/https://www.debuntu.org/2006/06/15/66-how-to-enable-apache-modules-under-debian-based-system

Answer (score 2):

You need just to copy those modules to some directory on Your system/server,
then add a command for appache in configure file.

ex:

```
LoadModule mod_proxy modules/mod_proxy.so  / linux
LoadModule mod_proxy modules/mod_proxy.dll  / windows
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule

Comment: is that true? i use XAMPP and other module just use .so file. I am on windows

Answer (score 1):

If your apache is built with shared library support, then you could copy these modules from another machine(same OS, same/lower version and preferably same compiler) and place it in modules folder. Then use LoadModule directive to dynamically load it.

If you dont have the modules, you can download the source and build/install apache in a different directory (using --prefix) with option --enable-mods-shared=most. Copy the required modules to the original apache modules folder, and use LoadModule to load it.